# How to pass an object from one view to another in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to pass an object from one view to another in my Django project. But I got an error such as `Object of type ModelCreate is not JSON serializable`

Here is my sender view:

```
@login_required(login_url = "user:login")
def modelCreate(request):
    customer_name = str(request.user)
    home_path = Methods.get_home_path(customer_name)

    outputs = request.user.profile.selected_outputs

    process = ModelCreate(str(home_path), customer_name, outputs)
    request.session['process'] = process
    return redirect("data:status")
```

Here is my receiver view;

```
@login_required(login_url = "user:login")
def process_status_view(request):
    process = request.session['process']
    return render(request, "pending_page.html")
```

How can I pass this object?

Comment: storing whole object in session may be an overkill, could eat you a lot resources. instead try request.session['process_id'] = process.id in your modelCreate and then you do 
`process_id = request.session.get('process_id')
if process_id:
process = ModelCreate.objects.get(id=process_id)
`

Comment: what about only having one view and a function that logs in the user and returns the users instance. for example the process_status_view can be your only view and takes in the parameters needed to pass to modelCreate() function to return a user instance

Comment: u re correct but this ModelCreate class is not a Django model so i cannot reach this object via db.

Comment: I have to have two views bcs when modelCreate triggered, the background task should be started and the when the process_status_view is redirected, i should display the status of process to user via ajax request.

Comment: You can not store the ModelCreate instance in session because its not json serializable, that is, it can not be converted into a string automatically. You can try representing it as a string, saving that value in the sesion, then in "process_status_view" view, read the string representation from  session and create a new ModelCreate instance with that data.

Comment: u re right. i've changed my solution way. thanks for answers.